# Help to understand the result in Granger Test

Tags: r, interpretation, granger-causality

I'm using the Granger test from package lmtest in R

This is the test

```
grangertest(dados$Publico_Total ~ dados$Classificacao)
```

I receive this result

```
Granger causality test
Model 1: dados$Publico_Total ~ Lags(dados$Publico_Total, 1:1) + Lags(dados$Classificacao, 1:1)
Model 2: dados$Publico_Total ~ Lags(dados$Publico_Total, 1:1)
  Res.Df Df      F  Pr(>F)  
1     64                    
2     65 -1 3.1352 0.08138 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

How I should interpret the results? I'm new doing this kind of est and not familiarized with the output

Answer (score 2):

If I look at the outputs generated , I can give some inference but do cross check just to be sure

1. Residual degrees of freedom for Model 1 and Model 2. Model 1 has 64 residual degrees of freedom, while Model 2 has 65.The difference in residual degrees of freedom between Model 1 and Model 2. In this case, -1 (65-64).
2. The F-statistic for the Granger causality test. The value is 3.1352, which represents the test statistic to compare the two models and the p-value is 0.08138.
3. Pr(>F): The p-value associated with the F-statistic. In this case, the p-value is 0.08138. If I take the threshold to be 0.05 so we cannot reject the null hypothesis since there is not enough evidence to conclude that Classificacao Granger causes Total.
4. Another thing I am worried about is marginal significance of 0.1 level at the p-value. This is generally considered a weak level of significance, and you should interpret it with caution.

Comment: 3. can --> cannot, since 0.08>0.05! Further, it is correct that *there is not enough evidence to conclude...*

Comment: Corrected it thanks